# How to look up the entries added to a table in last 5 seconds using Pymongo in python for mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I require to look up the entries added to my mongodb collection which were created or added in the past 10 seconds .

At present I do not have timestamp as part of the documents i have inserted into the collection. By reading stuff off google I understood that I can do this somehow using hte object id but I did not understand exactly how can I do it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
from datetime import datetime
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

newdate = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=-10)
dummy_id = ObjectId.from_datetime(newdate)

result = collection.find( { "_id": { "$gt": dummy_id } } )
```